# Binding multiple gstreamer video window to a single GTK widget(RTSP streaming)

Tags: gstreamer-1.0

I am creating a gstreamer camera application that streams multiple rtsp clients(cams) and i am trying to bind those videos to a single GTK widget. 
However, when i am running the app with single stream on gtk widget, it plays well by calling `gst_bus_set_sync_handler()` api that overlays the video on gtk widget as below:

```
overlay = GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY (GST_MESSAGE_SRC (message));
gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle (overlay, xid);

gst_message_unref (message);
```

**Now I am facing issues in binding multiple rtsp streaming videos, and not sure how to use `gst_bus_set_sync_handler()` for passing multiple messages.**
I tried by creating multiple drawing areas and XID's, still it does overlay only single video.

Please comment. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing exactly the same problem.
    It might be possible to embed multiple scenes in one window with analogy to this single sceen example using clutter-gst framework:

```
    https://github.com/ruby-gnome2/ruby-gnome2/issues/225
```

However, I already tried it, but when creating multiple clutter scenes :

```
GtkWidget *clutter0 = gtk_clutter_embed_new();
GtkWidget *clutter1 = gtk_clutter_embed_new();
```

And including them to GTK window:

```
GtkWidget *hbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hbox, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), clutter0, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), clutter1, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
tk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);
```

for better readibility I did not include the streaming code, but it's enough to generate the error

It yields this error for the second sceen I cannot resolve:

`(gstreamergtkclutterplayer:11614): Clutter-CRITICAL **: Unable to retrieve the geometry of the foreign window: XGetGeometry() failed (status code: 1)`

I think I read it is possible to open only one instance of a certain sink, for example gleglessink for one video stream and you cannot use this sink anymore, you have to use for example ximagesink, but from my experience, this does not apply to all the sinks, some of the sinks could be instantialized for many streams, however I want to achieve this with cluttersink as it gives you hardware acceleration.